# Is it possible to fabricate x.509 certificate with varying issuer and subject fields?

Tags: openssl, x.509

I'm testing a service that might not do a proper checks for the certificate chain but instead it checks issuer and subject fields only. I would need to create a (self signed?) certificate with different issuer and subject. Is this possible with OpenSSL

For example:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key mydomain.com.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=mydomain.com" -out mydomain.com.csr
```

Sets both issuer and subject with the same C/O/CN fields. I cannot find a params for openssl to force different fields. Any suggestions for alternative tool?

Comment: "with different issuer and subject" -- different from *what*?

Comment: When making your own certificate that will not actually be used for signing, you can put whatever you like in the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put self signed with a question mark without making clear if you understand what it means, namely a cert signed by the same key it contains (not just one *you* signed or caused to be signed). Or to be more exact, a cert signed by the private half of the keypair whose public half is contained in the cert, so that it *verifies* with its own key, although that verification is meaningless for security. If you do want that:

1. Create a keypair and a root-CA cert for that key. Any root-CA certs must, by definition, have subject=issuer and be self-signed i.e. signed by the same key it contains.
2. Create a child cert for that same keypair with a different subject name and other data as desired, issued/signed by the root-CA. It will thus be signed by the same keypair it contains, but have different names.
3. Use the child cert and if you don't need the root cert just discard it.

**If not self-signed that's the normal case.** Just create a CA keypair and cert, and then issue a child cert (or several) under that CA with a different name(s) and different keypair(s) and other data as desired. All certs, except root-CA and dummy/trivial self-signed EE certs, should always have subject not equal to issuer -- in fact using the same name for subject and issuer of a cert that *isn't* root or self-signed will usually confuse reliers and cause validation error or reject.

The one thing you can't do with OpenSSL is create cert(s) under -- that is, correctly signed by -- a 'real' CA like Verisign/Symantec/Digicert, GoDaddy, or LetsEncrypt. Thus any cert you create should not validate for any properly implemented relier by default, only if you or someone adds your 'local' CA to its truststore.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation, I clearly have some more studies to do with PKI and x.509 :-)